# Cannot POST datetime to API

Tags: python

I'm trying to POST datetime to my API but I keep getting this error:

```
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '

TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable
```

Code:

```
@Slot(int, int, int)
def postValues(self, getPostValue1, getPostValue2, getPostValue3):
    total = getPostValue1
    amountPaid = getPostValue2
    amountRemaining = getPostValue3
    customerID = 2
    userID = 3
    CurrentDateTime = datetime.datetime.now() 

    putData = {"customer_id": customerID, "total_amount": total, "amount_tendered": amountPaid, "date_recorded": CurrentDateTime, "user_id": userID, "amount_remaining": amountRemaining}

    post = requests.post("http://localhost:8085/api/invoice", json=putData)

    print("Invoice Data POST'ed", post.text)
```

I've looked at other questions highlighting the same issue, but I don't understand how I can incorporate it in my code. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just convert the value to whatever (string? Number?) your API is expecting, but you haven't told us what that is.

Comment: You need to convert your datetime to string of unix timestamp integer whatever your API is expecting, you are getting error because you can't put python datetime object in json you need to put either string, integer or float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the date-time value into a string. Change:

```
CurrentDateTime = datetime.datetime.now()
```

to:

```
CurrentDateTime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```